Check if name of collection element is included in collection element or any of it's children
I have a collection for "Folders". Each Folder gets an array of strings including the names of other folders called children.
A folder structure could for example look like this:

In this example, the children of "Animals" would be "Cats" and "Dogs", and the folder "Cats" would have the children "Domestic Cats" and "Lions". The folder "Pets" would have the children "Domestic Cats" and "Dogs".
I need to get the entire 'family tree' of a folder upwards. So if I have the folder "Domestic Cats" I need to find all its parents and the parents of those parents, and so on. In this example it'd be, "Cats", "Animals", and "Pets".
How could I achieve this using Liquid in Jekyll?

You can try recursively exploring the entire tree, and then printing the paths of every node whose name matches a desired value. Naturally, this will be quite slow, and will have multiple outputs in the event of multiple hits. This is a bit messy, since Liquid isn't really built for recursion.
Here's what you can try
search.liquid:


{% assign target = "target" %}
{% assign paths = "" %}

{% assign root = site.data.tree %}

{% for node in root %}
    {% include recurse.liquid node=node path="" %}
{% endfor %}

{{ paths }}



recurse.liquid


{% assign curr_path = path %}
{% assign curr_path = curr_path | append: "/" %}
{% assign curr_path = curr_path | append: node.name %}


{% if node.children %}
    {% for child in node.children %}
        {% if child.name == target %}
            {% assign curr_path = curr_path | append "/" %}
            {% assign curr_path = curr_path | append child.name %}
            {% assign paths = paths | append: curr_path %}
            {% assign paths = paths | append: ';' %}
        {% endif %}
        {% include recurse.liquid node=child path=curr_path %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}



I am a bit confused about the structure of your requirement, so my code will have to be adapted to your needs. For now, I have just written a generic recursive search. Also, I'm unsure by what you mean by "getting", but the paths are stores delimited by semicolons in paths, with / for showing nested directories.
This relies on a "name" attribute for every directory. If you do not have one, the conditional section of recurse.liquid will probably have to be modified too.

Hmm, unfortunately I seem to be getting the error Error: "Liquid error: Nesting too deep included"

Turns out you cannot nest conditionals in jekyll. I would recommend solving this problem using JS.
